systemctl redirect stdout/stderr of a java service to files in /var/my/appname/logs
I have a service running on RHEL9:
[Unit]
Description=My Application
After=syslog.target network.target
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/my/appname
ExecStart=java -Dlogging.config=/var/my/appname/myappname.logback.xml -jar /var/my/appname/myappname.jar /var/my/appname/myappname.gcptest.properties
ExecStop=/bin/kill 15 $MAINPID
Restart=on-failure
StandardOutput=file:/tmp/stdout.log
StandardError=file:/tmp/stderr.log
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

This works.
If I change the StandardOutput/StandardError, to file:/var/my/appname/logs/stdout.log, though, the service won't start up:
(code=exited, status=209/STDOUT)

Clearly there's some permissions issue somwhere.

The service file is in /etc/systemd/system; and so should be running as root, given that I don't specify a user.
The /var/my/appname/logs directory exists, and it and all parent directories under /var are root:root drwxrw-rw- permissions. /var itself is root:root drwxr-xr-x
I've also tried just logging to /var/my/stdout.log, but get the same issue.

Can anyone suggest why I can't write the logs to my /var subdirectory?
--update--
aureport -a showed me it was an SELinux issue; and setting SELinux to permissive (setenforce 0) allowed it to work. So, without disabling SELinux, how can I give the appropriate permissions to the service?

Can you sudo touch /var/my/appname/logs/stdout.log (when the file doesn't exist)? A bit far-fetched maybe, but could it be that you have some Apparmor profile / SELinux policy in place that is preventing Java from writing to /var/my/appname/logs?

What happens if you run and redirect the output directly from the shell with java ... >/var/my/appname/logs/stdout.log 2>&1?
When running from the shell you can also dig deeper with strace like strace -e %file java .....

@kos If I create the file beforehand, nothing happens - the file exists but doesn't get written to. /var/log/messages says: Sep 24 10:26:51 app-02 systemd[48954]: my.service: Failed to set up standard output: Permission denied
Sep 24 10:26:51 app-02 systemd[48954]: my.service: Failed at step STDOUT spawning java: Permission denied

@PaulPazderski running directly with a redirect in the shell ( as root) writes fine

aureport -a showed me it was an selinux issue; and setting selinux to permissive (setenforce 0) allowed it to work. SO, without disabling SELinux, how can I give the appropriate permissions to the service?

Try using audit2allow to convert the error message to a suitable fix.

Let us know if the duplicate helps.
